# Should my answer contain many possible solutions, or should I post multiple answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why “Please only post one answer to a question”?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3400/why-please-only-post-one-answer-to-a-question)

Some times, a question is a good question but maybe some what broad but not broad enough for it to close.

In these situations there could be many answers and some times giving multiple answers is more desirable as people could experience the same issues but different solutions are required.

My question is, where multiple answers are necessary, should they be done as separate posts or combined into one post? I assume common sense is needed, and if the answers are very similar, then combine, if varied then separate but I hate assumptions and so thought I'd ask first to see if there is a guide/rule.

Comment: I rarely see a point in posting multiple answers. We're really not a polling site. It's easy enough to post an answer containing multiple solutions

Comment: @slhck Yes, I agree, it's just that since I'm given the opportunity to post multiple answers, I thought it may indicate this is what is required. Thank you

Comment: This is not a definitive policy, which is why I didn't post an actual answer. Feel free to wait what others have to say :)

Comment: related / dupe [Why "Please only post one answer to a question"?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/3400)

Comment: @Sathya, Cool, this seems like the answer, although for the record, I did try and search for it before posting!

Comment: @DaveRook site search can be hit and a miss, I couldn't find on site search, so I checked the [tag:answers] tag posts :)